# how to pass struct from c++ to c# with lowest latency? (without marshalling it?)

Tags: c#, c++, latency

Currently to deliver struct from c++ to c# i declare it on both sides (c++ and c#) and use delegate. This approach is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318140/How-to-make-a-callback-to-Csharp-from-C-Cplusplus). In my opinion, for low latency applications, it could be not suitable because marshaling/unmarshalling spents CPU/memory and may affect performance when structure size is big enough, frequency of request is high enough and latency requirement is high enough.

For such, low latency, scenarios it would be better not to allocate extra memory but work with c++ memory in c# directly. I have found that one project uses `System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream` and `System.IO.BinaryReader` for that, then certain fields can be read for example this way:

```
reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream);
stream.Position = 8;
return reader.ReadInt32();
```

However I can not find complete example (how to have `UnmanagedMemoryStream` in c# which points to some structure or array of structures in c++?) I'm not sure this is best approach, but it could be so. What would you suggest for "low latency" transfer of structures from c++ to c#? Could you give an example?

I don't care about portability, maintainability etc. Only latency is important. It's temporary solution until I get rid of c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your C++ function and have it return a struct as a parameter. In C#, use the IntPtr type, and the use

```
DllImport("somedll.dll")
public static extern void SomeFunction(out IntPtr someStructParameterOutput);
```

And then:

```
IntPtr yourStruct;
SomeFunction(out yourStruct);
Stream s = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)yourStruct.ToPointer(), length);
```

Comment: why not returning "IntPtr" in function result? will this be faster then using approach described on codeproject?

Comment: @javapowered You could return it too. I dunno which method is faster, You would have to try it and see. You also do not need a memory stream. You can just use an unsafe code block and access it as a pointer with a memory offset just like you could in C

Comment: assume I delivered IntPtr to c# which point to certain c++ struct. How can I read certain members of this structure? I do not have duplicate of this structure in c#

Comment: I've found that i can use `Marshal.ReadInt64` and similar methods from `Marshal` class. Am I correct that this is recommended way of doing things?

Comment: @javapowered yeah that would work. There's several different ways you can do this.. You can define the struct in C# too and cast a pointer in C# to the struct pointer I believe. There is also Marshal.StructureToPointer and Marshal.PointerToStructure but I believe that methods does a memory copy into managed memory. My advice is to read through MS's documentation on marshaling different types.. It is really helpful if you haven't taken the time just to read it.

Comment: yes casting implies memory coping and it degrates latency. I've found that reading directly from unmanaged memory using Marshal.ReadInt64 etc. methods is several times faster.